# PHP reversing parents and children in array tree

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I've an array/tree with (endless) "parents" instead of children. It looks like this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Toplevel"
    ["parents"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "SecondLevel"
    ["parents"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["group_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "Toplevel"
        ["parents"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "ThirdLevel"
    ["parents"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["group_id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["name"]=>
        string(13) "SecondLevel"
        ["parents"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(3) {
            ["group_id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["name"]=>
            string(11) "TopLevel"
            ["parents"]=>
            NULL
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the tree structure is in reversed order. I want to rebuild the tree in the correct order with children as subnodes. It should look like this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Toplevel"
    ["children"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "TopLevel"
    ["children"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["group_id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "SecondLevel"
        ["children"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "TopLevel"
    ["children"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["group_id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["name"]=>
        string(13) "SecondLevel"
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(3) {
            ["group_id"]=>
            int(4)
            ["name"]=>
            string(11) "ThirdLevel"
            ["children"]=>
            NULL
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I just don't know how to do this. Is there any simple function that I can use, such as uasort?

**Update to answer questions:**

The array is built like this for this reason:

- User A can be member of different groups
- Groups can be member of different subgroups
- Subgroups can be member of different subsubgroups (and so on)

Now User A is in group 1 and 6. And 6 is a subgroup of 5, which is a subgroup of 4, which is a subgroup of 3. This means, that User A is also member of the groups 5,4,3. To fetch every group that is associated with User A, I'll look for each group he is direct member of (1 and 6) and lookup all the parents of these groups (results in: 1,3,4,5,6) with a recursive function:

```
private function getParentsArray($group_id) {
    $ret=null;
    $parents = $this->getGroupParents($group_id);

    if(!is_null($parents[0])) {
        foreach($parents as $parent) {
            $group = $this->getGroup($parent);
            if(!empty($this->getGroupParents($parent)) && $this->getGroupParents($parent)[0]) {
                $ret[] = array("group_id" => $group["group_id"], "name" => $group["name"], "parents" => $this->getParentsArray($group["group_id"]));
            } else {
                $ret[] = array("group_id" => $group["group_id"], "name" => $group["name"], "parents" => null);
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

**update 2:
here's var_export of the existing array, as requested:**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'group_id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Toplevel',
    'parents' => NULL,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'group_id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Secondlevel',
    'parents' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'group_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Toplevel',
        'parents' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'group_id' => 4,
    'name' => 'Thirdlevel',
    'parents' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'group_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Secondlevel',
        'parents' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'group_id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Toplevel',
            'parents' => NULL,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'group_id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Secondlevel2',
        'parents' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'group_id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Toplevel',
            'parents' => NULL,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'group_id' => 6,
    'name' => 'Firstlevel',
    'parents' => NULL,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'group_id' => 10,
    'name' => 'Forthlevel',
    'parents' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'group_id' => 9,
        'name' => 'Thirdlevel2',
        'parents' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'group_id' => 7,
            'name' => 'Secondlevel3',
            'parents' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'group_id' => 6,
                'name' => 'Firstlevel',
                'parents' => NULL,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Could you use `var_export($array)` and update your question so we can have the array? Also, if you have a code block that you tried something you should put it too..

Comment: Show us your code by using which you are building this array.

Comment: Are the multiple occurrences of TopLevel, SecondLevel and ThirdLevel _different_ elements? (Same name, same group id each time.) Or is your desired result data structure just needlessly redundant?

Comment: I updated the question with some infos. They're the same elements. @AntonisTsimourtos here's an export: https://pastebin.com/0UgGWAtr

Comment: Are you sure that output array should be as in question? Does not a group have to be presented once?

Comment: Sure, I can delete them later on, but my problem still exists. Shouldn't matter for the solution if there is redudance.

Comment: would you please update your array with valid php array look ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a count of the total parents

   **$parents** = $this->getGroupParents($group_id);
2. In for statement, store the array($ret[]) in reverse

   for($i==count($parents);$i>-1;$i--){
        $ret[$i] = '';
   }
3. Use key parent=>children